# Bootstrap on LASSO regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, feature-selection, lasso

I am doing LASSO regression in order to reduce the amount of independent variables a bit. In this case, it's not the only thing I am doing, but the LASSO is the last step. However, I have read that LASSO have its flaws (as does other things), so one trick is to bootstrap your population and run the LASSO (or full reduction scheme) to see if the frequency of the last selected independent variables are somewhat consistent.

My problem here is: What is a good frequency ? And what do I do, if let's say 4 independent variables end up being very frequent, but in total (over all bootstrap iterations), there have been 15 different or so. I mean, due to the LASSO penalties you end up with different intercepts, values etc. for the chosen variables compared to using them in a regular `glm`for example. So in my head it makes no sense to use LASSO to find the most frequent variables, and then use those in a `glm`.

So yeah, what should be my approach here ?